# How can I transform my unit cell positions to cartesian coordinates?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso

I have a structure with the parameters bellow:

```
ibrav = 0

 A = 6.05844

CELL_PARAMETERS {alat}

   0.497698628   0.497698628   0.000000000

   0.497698628   0.000000000   0.497698628

  -0.000000000   0.497698628   0.497698628
```

Can someone help me to convert them to cartesian coordinates, please?

Comment: As far as I understand from this [documentation](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PW.html#CELL_PARAMETERS) of Quantum Espresso, they are already in Cartesian form

Comment: Each of the three rows of the cell_parameter shows a lattice vector. The three columns are the Cartesian components. So, Here in angstrom unit, you have a unit cell with $\vec{a_1} = 3.01527728 \hat{x} + 3.01527728 \hat{y}$, $\vec{a_2} = 3.01527728 \hat{x} + 3.01527728 \hat{z}$ and $\vec{a_3} = 3.01527728 \hat{y} + 3.01527728 \hat{z}$ because `A=6.05844 angstrom` is the scaling factor and 0.497698628*6.05844=3.01527728

Answer (score 7):

If the cell is cubic, converting fractional coordinates to Cartesian coordinates is straight forward: just multiply any fractional coordinate by the cell vector.

Ex. Let suppose that the fractional coordinates are:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

and the cell parameters are A, B, and C in Angstroms, then, the coordinates in Angstroms are:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
x_1=a_1*A & y_1=b_1*B & z_1=c_1*C \\
x_2=a_2*A & y_2=b_2*B & z_2=c_2*C \\
x_3=a_3*A & y_3=b_3*B & z_3=c_3*C 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

If the cell is not cubic, the conversion has to take into account the cell angles ($\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, and $\alpha_3$):

${\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\y_2\\z_3\end{pmatrix}}={\begin{pmatrix}A\sin(\alpha _{2}){\sqrt {1-(\cot(\alpha _{1})\cot(\alpha _{2})-\csc(\alpha _{1})\csc(\alpha _{2})\cos(\alpha _{3}))^{2}}}&0&0\\
A\csc(\alpha _{1})\cos(\alpha _{3})-A\cot(\alpha _{1})\cos(\alpha _{2})&B\sin(\alpha _{1})&0\\
A\cos(\alpha _{2})&B\cos(\alpha _{1})&C\\\end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\b_2\\c_3\end{pmatrix}}$

For more details, the [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_coordinates) is a good starting point.